# elasticsearch python queries - Group by field and then count

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nosql, querydsl, kibana-4

I am stuck regarding an elasticsearch query using python

I have **data such as**:

```
{'_index': 'toto',
 '_type': 'tata',
 '_id': '9',
 '_version': 14,
 'found': True,
 '_source': {'Loss Event ID': 833,
  'Product': 'Sushi',
  'Company': 'SushiShop',
  'Profit': '10000000'}
}

{'_index': 'toto',
 '_type': 'tata',
 '_id': '11',
 '_version': 14,
 'found': True,
 '_source': {'Loss Event ID': 834,
  'Product': 'Burgers',
  'Company': 'McDonalds',
  'Profit': '4000000000'}
}

{'_index': 'toto',
 '_type': 'tata',
 '_id': '12',
 '_version': 14,
 'found': True,
 '_source': {'Loss Event ID': 836,
  'Product': 'Sushi',
  'Company': 'PlanetSushi',
  'Profit': '20000000'}
}
```

**Goal**: I would like to make a query using python - in keeping with group_by *Product* and count *Profit* to get this kind of result:

**Product | Profit**

> -> Sushi = 30000000
>
> -> Burgers = 4000000000
>
> (...)

Any help? I tried python DSL but it failed

```
enter code here

from time import time
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

import requests
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print(res.content)

#connect to our cluster
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

r = es.search(index='toto',
              doc_type='tata',
              body= {
    "query": { 
            "match" : { "Product": "Sushi" }
    },
    "aggs" : {
                "sum_income" : { "sum" : { "field" : "Profit" } }
    }
})
```

It fails... Tks

Comment: TIll now, what have you attempted?

Comment: from time import time
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

import requests
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print(res.content)

#connect to our cluster
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

r = es.search(index='toto',
              doc_type='tata',
              body= {
    "query": { 
            "match" : { "Product": "Sushi" }
    },
    "aggs" : {
                "sum_income" : { "sum" : { "field" : "Profit" } }
    }
})

Comment: First, you need to update your elasticsearch docs. Here `profit` is text or string type, convert it any numeric field, then apply aggregations. Below I provide to aggregation query.

Answer (score -1):

Use below aggregation query to get total profit for each product.

```
{
    "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
      "product_name": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "Product"
          },
          "aggs": {
              "total_profit": {
                  "sum": {
                      "field": "Profit"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

**Note**: `Profit` field must be any numeric type.